# Kendo jQuery Inline Grid Validation is not working as needed

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, grid

I'm trying to use KENDO UI to validated 2 values in a grid row.
These 2 values, HOURS and COUNT are mutually exclusive, so if they both have a value > 0, I would like to signal an error.

Two behavior issues I'm having:

1. The error "Both Hours and Count are not allowed" displays, but it only triggers on the second iteration of erroneous input.
   Example input:     Hours  / Count
   1        0    (good)
   1        1    (should result an error)
   1        2    (this fires the desired error)
2. Once the error displays, I can't determine how to remove it. If I correct the data setting one of the inputs back to zero, the error remains.

I'm using function FCTest to validate, but I can only assume I need to call it again, or in a different sequence to get the timing corrected.

Thanks,
Robert

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- TEST -->
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: [
                        { id: 1, count: 1, hours: 0},
                        { id: 2, count: 0, hours: 1},
                    ],

                    pageSize: 20,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "id",
                            fields: {
                                id: { editable: false },

                                count: {editable: true,type: "number",
                                        validation:{
                                                    required:true,
                                                    maxlength:"3",
                                                    FCValid: FCTest}},

                                hours: {editable: true, type: "number",
                                    validation:{required:true,
                                        maxlength:"2"}}}
                            }
                        }
     });


        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                {field: "id", title: "ID", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px"},
                {field: "count", title: "Count", width: "120px"},
                {field: "hours", title: "Hours", width: "120px"},
                {command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px"}],
            editable: "inline"
        });

 }); // end document ready


        function FCTest(input) {
            var row = input.closest("tr");
            var grid = row.closest("[data-role=grid]").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

            // if (parseFloat(input.val()) <= .1) {
            //     input.attr("data-FCValid-msg", "Decimals not allowed");
            //     return false;
            // }
            console.log({row});
            console.log({dataItem});
            console.log(dataItem.hours);
            console.log(dataItem.count);

            if (parseFloat(dataItem.hours) > 0 && (parseFloat(dataItem.count) > 0)) {
                input.attr("data-FCValid-msg", "Both Hours and Count are not allowed");
                return false;
            }

            if (parseFloat(dataItem.hours) == 0 && (parseFloat(dataItem.count) == 0)) {
                input.attr("data-FCValid-msg", "Must contain one Frequency value: Hours or Count");
                return false;
            }

            return true;

        }
    </script>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the cellClose, check if the incoming model is not a new row, and then check if the values meet your conditions:

```js
cellClose: function(e) {
  if (!e.model.isNew()) {
    if (e.model.count > 0 && e.model.hours > 0) {
      kendo.alert('Both Hours and Count are not allowed');
    } else if (e.model.count == 0 && e.model.hours == 0) {
      kendo.alert('Must contain one Frequency value: Hours or Count');
    }
  }
}
```

Dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/oxAkUpAs

Comment: David, thanks for the code! Question: what about using the cellClose in conjunction with editable: inline - from the documentation I see, that won't work. It will have to be editable: true?

Comment: @RobertCrowe - yeah, the only way that the cellClose event gets raised is if the editable type is incell (which is used by default when `editable: true` is used).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!